# OWASP 2010 - Security Misconfiguration example

Tags: php, security, owasp

I am working with PHP and the OWASP 2010 TOP 10 and need your help :)

I need an example of how to use [Security Misconfiguration](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A6), I think I need to know how to bug then I can know how to prevent. I've tried to find some via google but mostly only got concept of it. I need an actual example so I can understand this clearlier :)

Comment: Please define *OWASP 2010 PHP*.

Comment: I mean OWASP top 10 2010 and I use PHP

Comment: This is an example video of it, it demonstrates with an exemplary PHP application: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOHZzmGJTeg - Keep in mind that *Security Misconfiguration* is not really PHP specific (review your php.ini for example for the production system(s)), that is probably why you're having a hard time to find PHP specific resources.

Answer (score 1):

So there's one really good example of [A6 - Security Misconfiguration](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A6) in PHP. Well, there was one until 5.4.0. It was called [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). If you had register_globals on, it opened several potential doors for vulnerabilities.

Another good misconfiguration is if you have [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on in production. This is a problem, because any errors are disclosed to the user (potentially giving them clues to your filesystem structure and potential vulnerable error-producing parts of the application.